# Click me button

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have no idea what I am doing wrong here but `click me` button doesn't work why? I want in the first click me to change the color of the first and the second click me to change the color of the second paragraph. In any case, click's don't work. I have to look at my functions but can't see what I did wrong. Maybe needs to create other function that will make them work? That's all,the button click are not working on that code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <h1>Tv Shows</h1>


    <div class="bg-image img1">
      <p id="demo">My Top 5 Tv shows,is Prison Break,Wayward Pines,Mentalist,Lost,Usa shooter</p>
      <button onclick="myFunction()">click me</button>
    </div>
    <div class="bg-image img2">
      <p id="demo1">My Top 5 movies,is Run all Night ,Asterix and Obelix,,Lost,Usa
      shooter</p>
      <button onclick="myFunction()">click me</button>
    </div>
    <style>

    body, html {
      height: 100%;
      margin: 0;
      font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    }

    * {
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }

    .bg-image {
      /* Full height */
      height: 50%; 

      /* Center and scale the image nicely */
      background-position: center;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      background-size: cover;
    }

    /* Images used */
    .img1 { background-image: url("https://images.pexels.com/photos/1115804/pexels-photo-1115804.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=750&w=1260"); }
    .img2 { background-image: url("https://images.pexels.com/photos/3989816/pexels-photo-3989816.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=750&w=1260"); }


    /* Position text in the middle of the page/image */
    .bg-text {
      background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
      background-color: rgba(0,0,0, 0.4); /* Black w/opacity/see-through */
      color: white;
      font-weight: bold;
      font-size: 80px;
      border: 10px solid #f1f1f1;
      position: fixed;
      top: 50%;
      left: 50%;
      transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
      z-index: 2;
      width: 300px;
      padding: 20px;
      text-align: center;
    }
    function myFunction() {
      var x = document.getElementById("demo");
      x.style.fontSize = "25px"; 
      x.style.color = "red"; 
    }

    function mySec() {
      var x = document.getElementById("demo1");
      x.style.fontSize = "25px"; 
      x.style.color = "green"; 
    }

    </style>
    </head>
    <body>



    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Visible markup goes between`<body></body>` tag, CSS between `<style></style>` tag, javascript between `<script></script>` tag

Comment: @ZohirSalak still don't get my mistakes if you can answer so I can tick also

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to use tag script some code /script

```js
    function myFunction() {
      var x = document.getElementById("demo");
      x.style.fontSize = "25px"; 
      x.style.color = "red"; 
    }

    function mySec() {
      var x = document.getElementById("demo1");
      x.style.fontSize = "25px"; 
      x.style.color = "green"; 
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
 
    <h1>Tv Shows</h1>


    <div class="bg-image img1">
      <p id="demo">My Top 5 Tv shows,is Prison Break,Wayward Pines,Mentalist,Lost,Usa shooter</p>
      <button onclick="myFunction()">click me</button>
    </div>
    <div class="bg-image img2">
      <p id="demo1">My Top 5 movies,is Run all Night ,Asterix and Obelix,,Lost,Usa
      shooter</p>
      <button onclick="mySec()">click me</button>
    </div>
    <style>

    body, html {
      height: 100%;
      margin: 0;
      font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    }

    * {
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }

    .bg-image {
      /* Full height */
      height: 50%; 

      /* Center and scale the image nicely */
      background-position: center;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      background-size: cover;
    }

    /* Images used */
    .img1 { background-image: url("https://images.pexels.com/photos/1115804/pexels-photo-1115804.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=750&w=1260"); }
    .img2 { background-image: url("https://images.pexels.com/photos/3989816/pexels-photo-3989816.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=750&w=1260"); }


    /* Position text in the middle of the page/image */
    .bg-text {
      background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
      background-color: rgba(0,0,0, 0.4); /* Black w/opacity/see-through */
      color: white;
      font-weight: bold;
      font-size: 80px;
      border: 10px solid #f1f1f1;
      position: fixed;
      top: 50%;
      left: 50%;
      transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
      z-index: 2;
      width: 300px;
      padding: 20px;
      text-align: center;
    }
     </style>
  
   
    </head>
    <body>



    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: try now. its work. in the second you used the wrong function

Answer (score 1):

First of all the syntax used in the code is not correct. Best way is to use single function and pass id of the `<p>` tag. Below is the updated code

```
<html>

<head>

    <style>
        body,
        html {
            height: 100%;
            margin: 0;
            font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        }

        * {
            box-sizing: border-box;
        }

        .bg-image {
            /* Full height */
            height: 50%;
            /* Center and scale the image nicely */
            background-position: center;
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            background-size: cover;
        }
        /* Images used */

        .img1 {
            background-image: url("https://images.pexels.com/photos/1115804/pexels-photo-1115804.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=750&w=1260");
        }

        .img2 {
            background-image: url("https://images.pexels.com/photos/3989816/pexels-photo-3989816.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=750&w=1260");
        }
        /* Position text in the middle of the page/image */

        .bg-text {
            background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
            /* Fallback color */
            background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
            /* Black w/opacity/see-through */
            color: white;
            font-weight: bold;
            font-size: 80px;
            border: 10px solid #f1f1f1;
            position: fixed;
            top: 50%;
            left: 50%;
            transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
            z-index: 2;
            width: 300px;
            padding: 20px;
            text-align: center;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>Tv Shows</h1>
    <div class="bg-image img1">
        <p id="demo">My Top 5 Tv shows,is Prison Break,Wayward Pines,Mentalist,Lost,Usa shooter</p>
        <button onclick="myFunction('demo')">click me</button>
    </div>
    <div class="bg-image img2">
        <p id="demo1">My Top 5 movies,is Run all Night ,Asterix and Obelix,,Lost,Usa shooter
        </p>
        <button onclick="myFunction('demo1')">click me</button>
    </div>

    <script>
        function myFunction(id) {
            var x = document.getElementById(id);
            x.style.fontSize = "25px";
            x.style.color = "red";
        }
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: @maikl From the code perspective, always use single function to perform same task. Here you have to `<p>` tags and you are using two different functions. If in future you have 5 more tags, will you add more 5 functions, even though they are redundant. So always try to use an efficient method.

Answer (score 0):

Would you try it this way ? I edited the tags that were wrong.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <style>
        body,
        html {
            height: 100%;
            margin: 0;
            font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        }

        * {
            box-sizing: border-box;
        }

        .bg-image {
            /* Full height */
            height: 50%;

            /* Center and scale the image nicely */
            background-position: center;
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            background-size: cover;
        }

        /* Images used */
        .img1 {
            background-image: url("https://images.pexels.com/photos/1115804/pexels-photo-1115804.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=750&w=1260");
        }

        .img2 {
            background-image: url("https://images.pexels.com/photos/3989816/pexels-photo-3989816.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=750&w=1260");
        }


        /* Position text in the middle of the page/image */
        .bg-text {
            background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
            /* Fallback color */
            background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
            /* Black w/opacity/see-through */
            color: white;
            font-weight: bold;
            font-size: 80px;
            border: 10px solid #f1f1f1;
            position: fixed;
            top: 50%;
            left: 50%;
            transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
            z-index: 2;
            width: 300px;
            padding: 20px;
            text-align: center;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>Tv Shows</h1>
    <div class="bg-image img1">
        <p id="demo">My Top 5 Tv shows,is Prison Break,Wayward Pines,Mentalist,Lost,Usa shooter</p>
        <button onclick="myFunction()">click me</button>
    </div>
    <div class="bg-image img2">
        <p id="demo1">My Top 5 movies,is Run all Night ,Asterix and Obelix,,Lost,Usa
            shooter</p>
        <button onclick="myFunction()">click me</button>
    </div>

    <script>
        function myFunction() {
            var x = document.getElementById("demo");
            x.style.fontSize = "25px";
            x.style.color = "red";
        }

        function mySec() {
            var x = document.getElementById("demo1");
            x.style.fontSize = "25px";
            x.style.color = "green";
        }
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: ` <button onclick="mySec()">click me</button>` just copy this. ıts working now. you wrong select function name.

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
body, html { height: 100%; margin: 0; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; } * { box-sizing: border-box; } .bg-image { /* Full height */ height: 50%; /* Center and scale the image nicely */ background-position: center; background-repeat: no-repeat; background-size: cover; } /* Images used */ .img1 { background-image: url("https://images.pexels.com/photos/1115804/pexels-photo-1115804.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=750&w=1260"); } .img2 { background-image: url("https://images.pexels.com/photos/3989816/pexels-photo-3989816.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=750&w=1260"); } /* Position text in the middle of the page/image */ .bg-text { background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */ background-color: rgba(0,0,0, 0.4); /* Black w/opacity/see-through */ color: white; font-weight: bold; font-size: 80px; border: 10px solid #f1f1f1; position: fixed; top: 50%; left: 50%; transform: translate(-50%, -50%); z-index: 2; width: 300px; padding: 20px; text-align: center; }
</style>

<script> function myFunction() { var x = document.getElementById("demo"); x.style.fontSize = "25px"; x.style.color = "red"; } function mySec() { var x = document.getElementById("demo1"); x.style.fontSize = "25px"; x.style.color = "green"; }
</script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Tv Shows</h1>
        <div class="bg-image img1">
            <p id="demo">My Top 5 Tv shows,is Prison Break,Wayward Pines,Mentalist,Lost,Usa shooter</p>
            <button onclick="myFunction()">click me</button>
        </div>
        <div class="bg-image img2">
            <p id="demo1">My Top 5 movies,is Run all Night ,Asterix and Obelix,,Lost,Usa shooter</p>
            <button onclick="myFunction()">click me</button>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

You enclosed the Javascript code in `<style>` tags, they should be enclosed in `<script>` tags